# Android Titanium Appcelerator - Path must be a string. Received null

Tags: android, node.js, titanium, appcelerator

I'm working on a project using Titanium & Alloy and I'm finally able to run the iOS version, but I got an error with Android when I run the `appc ti build -p android` command.

Everything seems to work until the `Building Java source files` step

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/javac  
"-J-Xmx1024M" "-encoding" "utf8" "-bootclasspath" "/Users/fharper/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-
23/android.jar:/Users/fharper/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.1.GA/android/kroll-v8.jar:
/Users/fharper/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-analytics.jar:
/Users/fharper/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.1.GA/android/aps-analytics.jar:
/Users/fharper/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-android.jar:
/Users/fharper/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.1.GA/android/jaxen-1.1.1.jar:
/Users/fharper/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.1.GA/android/ti-commons-codec-1.3.jar:
/Users/fharper/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.1.GA/android/kroll-common.jar:
/Users/fharper/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.1.GA/android/titanium.jar:
/Users/fharper/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.1.GA/android/android-support-multidex.jar:
/Users/fharper/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-filesystem.jar:
/Users/fharper/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-app.jar:
/Users/fharper/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-ui.jar:
/Users/fharper/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.1.GA/android/nineoldandroids-appc-2.4.0.jar:
/Users/fharper/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-media.jar:
/Users/fharper/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-appcompat.jar:
/Users/fharper/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.1.GA/android/android-support-v4.jar:
/Users/fharper/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.1.GA/android/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar:
/Users/fharper/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-cardview.jar:
/Users/fharper/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.1.GA/android/cardview-v7-23.0.1.jar:
/Users/fharper/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-locale.jar:
/Users/fharper/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-network.jar:
/Users/fharper/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-xml.jar:
/Users/fharper/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-platform.jar:
/Users/fharper/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-gesture.jar:
/Users/fharper/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-database.jar:
/Users/fharper/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-geolocation.jar:
/Users/fharper/Documents/Code/TheProject/TheProject/modules/android/ti.compression/3.0.0/compression.jar:
/Users/fharper/Documents/Code/TheProject/TheProject/modules/android/analytics.google/3.2.0/analytics.google.jar:
/Users/fharper/Documents/Code/TheProject/TheProject/modules/android/analytics.google/3.2.0/lib/google-play-services-analytics.jar:
/Users/fharper/Documents/Code/TheProject/TheProject/modules/android/analytics.google/3.2.0/lib/google-play-services-base.jar:
/Users/fharper/Documents/Code/TheProject/TheProject/modules/android/analytics.google/3.2.0/lib/google-play-services-basement.jar:
/Users/fharper/Documents/Code/TheProject/TheProject/modules/android/analytics.google/3.2.0/lib/play-services-analytics-impl.jar:
/Users/fharper/Documents/Code/TheProject/TheProject/modules/android/com.ideeclic.insitu.insituwebserver/2.0.0/insituwebserver.jar:
/Users/fharper/Documents/Code/TheProject/TheProject/modules/android/ti.map/3.0.1/map.jar:/Users/fharper/Documents/Code/TheProject/TheProject/modules/android/ti.map/3.0.1/lib/google-play-services-map.jar:
/Users/fharper/Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules/android/com.alcoapps.actionbarextras/1.7.3/actionbarextras.jar:
/Users/fharper/Documents/Code/TheProject/TheProject/modules/android/com.tripvi.drawerlayout/2.0.0/drawerlayout.jar:
/Users/fharper/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.1.GA/android/kroll-apt.jar:
/Users/fharper/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.1.GA/android/lib/titanium-verify.jar:Manifest.class:R.class:AssetCryptImpl.class:Insitu2TheProjectActivity.class:Insitu2TheProjectAppInfo.class:Insitu2TheProjectApplication.class" "-d" 
"/Users/fharper/Documents/Code/TheProject/TheProject/build/android/bin/classes" "-proc:none" "-target" "1.6" "-source" "1.6" "@/Users/fharper/Documents/Code/TheProject/TheProject/build/android/java-sources.txt"
```

where I get the following error

```
An uncaught exception was thrown!
Path must be a string. Received null
Path must be a string. Received null
```

I never used Titanium (6.0.1.GA - CLI 5.0.14), don't have access to previous developer and didn't use much Node (6.11.2) also even if I know JavaScript, so I'm stuck. I tried many things like changing the Titanium SDK, Java JDK (1.8.0_121), Android SDK (6.0 API 23 rev 3), but nothing works and iOS is running now. I'm not even sure where this error happens. I have the issues even if I use the AppceleratorStudio to try to run the app.

Any idea? I spent too much time on this and really need to move forward... Thanks a lot!

**Update**

Here is the full log (too big to paste directly in SO) when I run the `appc run -p android --build-only -l trace` command: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13087140/StackOverflow/build_android.log

Comment: You can try using the command 'appc run -p android --build-only -l trace'. This will generate a log in the console and will give you information when does the problem happen. If you could share it, it will give me some lead where to look for.

Comment: Thanks, I added the log file to the initial question. I'll give it another closer look, but at first, still don't see where I should look for...

Comment: It's too big to be pasted here (limitation of StackOverflow), but the link to a .log file is in the question. Here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13087140/StackOverflow/build_android.log

Comment: @YvetteColomb: it's the log from the command line with trace mode. It's why I have issue finding what is the problem as the only error you can find in the log is: An uncaught exception was thrown! Path must be a string. Received null Path must be a string. Received null

Comment: Even when I try to build it from within AppceleratorStudio (I guess it used the CLI to compile), I get the same error (here are the four last lines as the maximum characters for comment are too short - same as the one I have in the log file from the CLI):

2017-08-05T12:39:33.998Z | ERROR  | An uncaught exception was thrown!
Path must be a string. Received null
2017-08-05T12:39:33.998Z | ERROR  | Path must be a string. Received null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this issue was to upgrade the Android SDK Tools from 23.0.2 to 26.0.1, even if not tested and supported by Appcelerator Titanium for now.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with appcelerator and basically, it hasn't been fixed for certain configurations - the devs have been having difficulty reproducing the error, so it seems the exact version choice for titanium and  node  is important.

["Path must be a string. Received undefined" error is thrown if you build to Android using Node 6.X.X strictly with Appc CLI](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/CLI-1056)

> Resolution: Won't Fix

One user's fix.

The developer has closed the issue and there is conflict about whether the issue has been solved.

> Will close ticket as won't fix. Confirmed that I do not get this error any more with
>   Appc CLI Core 5.4.0-36 with Ti SDK 6.0.0.v20160728020336.

and

> I am still unable to reproduce this issue with the current GA stack:
>   Appc CLI NPM: 4.2.8
>   Appc CLI Core: 6.1.0
>   SDK: 6.0.1.GA
>   Node: v6.9.2
>   OS: Mac OS X (10.12.2)
>   If possible, when running the mobile project, include the debug and trace logs: DEBUG=* appc run -l trace.

Now you're using:

Titanium (6.0.1.GA - CLI 5.0.14)
Node (6.11.2)

Try using older sdks for titanium and an earlier node version. I don't see it being an issue with the Android sdk.

One user resolved it by downgrading node

> I resolved it by using node v4x. It does not work with v6.x which I was using when I saw the error.

From github:

[appcelerator/titanium Path must be a string. Received undefined](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium/issues/248)

From the devs:

The obvious check of all paths:

> The first thing I would do is look at both your Appc CLI and Titanium CLI config files and see if there are any settings that look like paths that are undefined, null, or empty and fixing them. You can find them at ~/.appcelerator/appc-cli.json and ~/.titanium/config.json.

and downgrading versions:

> So this happens because of some changes in Node.js that affect 5.5.1.GA. If your app needs to stay on SDK 5.5.1.GA try to downgrade your Node version to a 4.X version, otherwise upgrading to SDK 6.0.1.GA should fix the issue.

The other issue that is always worth mentioning - is to uninstall and install fresh sdks, in case there's been some changes or flaw in the current ones that were imported with the project you've inherited.

Comment: Thanks Yvette!


The issue was finally the Android SDK Tools that I needed to upgrade to the latest version, 26.0.1, even if not supported or tested by Appcelerator.


What brought me there was your answer. I tried to downgrade to Node v4.x, and I got a different error at the same step, when building the Java source files:


`[ERROR] Failed to run dexer:
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Error: Unable to access jarfile null3`


With that error, I found that the issue may be an Android SDK Tools one, upgraded and it worked. I was also able to go back to Node v6.x and everything is compiling now.

Comment: I'll award you the bounty, but for whatever reason, I can only do it in 9h... Thanks again!